# Scrapy: Get some information from another page

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to add the location for my scraped data from another page. Currently, I only get the following response while expecting e.g. "Paris, France"

```
{'pk': 1100, 'name': 'Car Ralley 42 2016', 'start': '2016-11-25', **'location': <GET https://www.somepage.com/festivals/carralley-november/42-2016/>**}
```

**spider.py**

```
class SomeSpider(Spider):
    if not DEBUG:
        custom_settings = {
            "DOWNLOAD_DELAY": "3",
        }

    handle_httpstatus_list = [404]
    name = "somedomain"
    _http404status_count = 0

    def start_requests(self):
        """Initialize DynamoDB and get the last PK which was crawled."""

        self.database = DynamoDB(self.settings, DYNAMODB_TABLE, DYNAMODB_ITEM)
        self._pk = self.database.get_pk()
        yield scrapy.Request(
            f"https://www.somedomain.com/api-internal/v1/festivals/{self._pk}/?format=json"
        )

    def parse_event_location(self, response):
        location = response.xpath('//li[@class="styles__c-h0jg7b-2 jhidiL"]/text()').get()
        yield location

    def parse(self, response):
        if self._http404status_count == HTTP404STATUS_MAX:
            raise CloseSpider(f"Reached {HTTP404STATUS_MAX} 404 responses in a row.")

        if response.status == 404:
            self._http404status_count += 1
        elif response.status == 200:
            self._http404status_count = 0  # Reset _http404status_count
            body = json.loads(response.body)

            festicket_detail_page = body.get("url")
            if festicket_detail_page:
                location = response.follow(
                    festicket_detail_page,
                    callback=self.parse_event_location
                )

            yield {
                "pk": body.get("pk"),
                "name": body.get("name"),
                "start": body.get("start"),
                "location": location
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I could find a solution [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions).